# How to insert record of python datetime and timezone info into oracle timestamp with zone column using sqlachemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-datetime

I have existing oracle databases which has table 'STUDENT'. Below are the fields and datatypes of table:

```
ID -- NUMBER
NAME -- VARCHAR(100)
CREATED_DATE -- TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp allow null
MODIFIED_DATE -- TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp allow null
```

I am able to connect the oracle database using sqlalchemy as mentioned below:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'cx_oracle'
USERNAME = '******'
PASSWORD = '******'
HOST = '*******'
PORT = 1521
SERVICE = '*****'
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE
engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH, max_identifier_length=128, echo=True, connect_args={"encoding": "utf-8"})

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
```

I am able to map the tables from oracle database into sqlalchemy objects using below code:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
STUDENT = Base.classes.student
db_session = Session(engine)
```

After the above code, I have wrote a code to insert data into table using sqlalchemy.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
data = [(1, 'stud1'), (2,'stud2'), (3, 'stud3')]
for d in data:
    date_created = datetime.now(timezone('Europe/London'))
    date_modified = datetime.now(timezone('Europe/London'))
    
    stud_record = STUDENT(id=d[0], name=d[1], created_date=date_created, modified_date = date_modified)
    db_session.add(stud_record)
db_session.commit()
```

After execution of code I am able to insert the record into table but I can see the datetime and timestamp value in `created_date` and `modified_date` column. e.g **(13-JAN-21 04.23.41.343000000 +00:00)**

I also want timezone value in that column like. e.g **13-JAN-21 04.23.41.343000000 EUROPE/LONDON**

Please suggest me what I did wrong in the code, how I can insert python datetime and timestamp value into oracle table column(TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE) using `sqlalchemy`?.

Comment: What do you get from `select TO_CHAR(created_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I got this response `2021-01-13 08:40:41 +00`.

Comment: Are your sure? Time zone `+00` does not exist, see `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE tzname = '+00'`

Comment: Yes, I got the same response from column.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one: [Mastering Oracle+Python, Part 2: Working with Times and Dates](https://developer.oracle.com/dsl/prez-python-times-and-dates.html) where it states:

> Important things to remember about cx_Oracle 4.3 in the datetime context:
>
> - no support for INTERVAL and TIMESTAMP WITH (LOCAL) TIME ZONE

I think the solution is this:

If a client sends a timestamp without time zone information (which seems to be the case with python) then Oracle defaults time zone to `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

Run `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'` in python after you connected to Oracle. Or set environment variable `ORA_SDTZ=Europe/London`

Comment: Yes, I saw that but it was quite old thread in the year 2007 as well as information. Thanks, I will check with environment variable. Also I am not using `cx_Oracle`.